# Delphi: MDI window underlapping

Tags: delphi, mdi

I am trying to create an MDI interface in my application, I am using Delphi XE2. I have a TTreeView on the left side, a TMenu (Of course on the top.) and thats all there is in the MDIParent window. Now here is where the problem shows up:
The MDI Child window is created, but it is under-lappping(opposite of "Over-Lapping") the TTreeView, and this isn't the only problem, If the I maximize it, a portion of it will go under the TTreeView! And if you want the code I am using to create the MDI Childs, Here it is:

TSprEditorForm.Create(Application);

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is how it looks like:
http://s5.postimg.org/v82qe9s2f/bg1.png
http://s5.postimg.org/c49exxf87/bg2.png

Comment: This is possible to get right. We can't see how you made your tree view.

Comment: Now I've added some screenshots, Can you please help me now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `Align` property of the TreeView to `alLeft`.

Comment: Thanks a LOT! And just before five minutes, I found another work-around: Use a TSplitter. But anyways, I am using your method.

Comment: I would up-rep you but I don't have much reputation